# why complement searchlist doesn't work?

Tags: perl

I expect `"abc" =~ /\Aabc\z/gc;` to be false, as `/c` is there,like in this case:

```
$pathname =˜ tr/a-zA-Z/_/cs; # change non-(ASCII)alphas to single underbar
```

But it turns out to be `true`, anyone can explain the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) for what `/c` actually does (Applied to a regexp match operator it doesn't complement as it would with `tr///`).  Transliteration is not a regexp, and regexen are not transliterations.

From perlretut:

> A failed match or changing the target string resets the position. If
>   you don't want the position reset after failure to match, add the //c
>   , as in /regexp/gc .

Virtually the same passage appears in perlrequick.

perlre makes it a little harder to search for, but here's what it says:

> **g and c**
>   Global matching, and keep the Current position after failed matching.
>   Unlike i, m, s and x, these two flags affect the way the regex is used
>   rather than the regex itself. See Using regular expressions in Perl in
>   perlretut for further explanation of the g and c modifiers.

Answer (score 6):

`/c` does not do 'complement' matching :)

```
"abc" !~ /abc/;  # false
```

To disallow `abc` anywhere in the string you *could* do

```
/((?!abc).)*\z/
```

but it would be much less efficient

EDIT:

#### `/gc` *modifier*: (from [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Global-matching))

> A failed match or changing the target string resets the position. If you don't want the position reset after failure to match, add the `//c` , as in `/regexp/gc` . The current position in the string is associated with the string, not the regexp. This means that different strings have different positions and their respective positions can be set or read independently.

Comment: what does `/c` do with matching then?

Comment: @new_perl: see `perldoc perlre` and `perldoc perlretut` (also edited answer)

Comment: @ColinFine: nice. I wasn't aware of that operator

Comment: I was going to fix your post and leave an explanation in the comments since I thought you were simply missing one character, but all three of your answers are wrong. So is @Colin Fine's. `if (/.../g)` makes no sense conceptually, so it definitely doesn't do what you intend it to do, and it can cause errors. I posted correct versions in an answer.

Comment: @ikegami I agree that leaving the `/g` in was silly; I somehow mdae the mistake of staying too close to the original code (it happens to me when the actual intent isn't entirely clear). To be honest, I still don't think the OP's intent is totally clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if something isn't in a string, I recommend

```
$str !~ /abc/
```

which is short for

```
!( $str =~ /abc/ )
```

You could also use the following, but it's needlessly complex (and slow?):

```
$str =~ /^(?:(?!abc).)*\z/s
```